# NSPopover cannot be dragged out

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstabview, nspopover

I have an `NSPopover` that contains an `NSTabView` which encloses all the popover's content view area. In this setup, I could not drag out the popover even though I've implemented `detachableWindowForPopover:` correctly in the delegate. I know I have implemented the delegate correctly because if the the tab view's size is reduced slightly (to uncover it's parent view), the popover can be dragged out into its own window.

Question is: How to make the popover can be detached by grabbing any blank area in the tab view?

Here's my object composition hierarchy

```
NSPopover 
    -> content view controller (NSViewController)
        -> the content view controller's view (NSView)
            -> NSTabView
               -> (some other views and their controllers for each tab)
```

Comment: Won't you need to drag from an area of the `NSPopover` that isn't covered by its enclosing view controller?

Comment: @trojanfoe I can drag an area covered by the view controller's view but couldn't drag an area covered by the tab view.

Comment: But isn't that what you'd expect to happen?  Sounds to me like it's just that the tabview is "consuming" the mouse events and they are not being passed to the window?  I am guessing though.

Comment: @trojanfoe There are large areas of "blank" spaces that should be draggable. Indeed these same blank spaces drags the window should it is already detached.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in `NSPopover` then.

Comment: @trojanfoe it's easy to point the blame to Apple, but still the question remains.